# Sending data from arduino to java

Tags: java, arduino

Hello im working on a project for myself. i have serveral RFID cards. I want to send a RFID code(cardID) to my arduino and then scan a random rfid card. if the sent RFID code and the one scaned are matching i want to send back a string/number or just one byte back to my java programm.

so far sending to my arduino and checking the RFID card is working fine however im stuck at sending something back to my java programm.
i was thinking about using serielConnection but tbh its very difficult to understand.
can someone help me out ?
thanks in advance

my java code

```
    package test;

import java.io.IOException;

import com.fazecast.jSerialComm.SerialPort;

public class Startup {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        SerialPort sp = SerialPort.getCommPort("COM4"); // device name TODO: must be changed
        sp.setComPortParameters(115200, 8, 33, 34); // 9600,8,1,0default connection settings for Arduino
        sp.setComPortTimeouts(SerialPort.TIMEOUT_WRITE_BLOCKING, 0, 0); // block until bytes can be written
        
        if (sp.openPort()) {
          System.out.println("Port is open :)");
        } else {
          System.out.println("Failed to open port :(");
          return;
        }       
        
        /*for (Integer i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {         
          sp.getOutputStream().write(i.byteValue());
          sp.getOutputStream().flush();
          System.out.println("Sent number: " + i);
          Thread.sleep(4000); //default 1000
        }       
        */
        //rfid tag  0x82,130
        //rfid card 118
        
        Integer i = 0;//0x82,130
        sp.getOutputStream().write(i.byteValue());
          sp.getOutputStream().flush();
          System.out.println("Sent number: " + i);
          Thread.sleep(8000);
        
        
        
        if (sp.closePort()) {
          System.out.println("Port is closed :)");
        } else {
          System.out.println("Failed to close port :(");
          return;
        }
        
        //from arduino
        
     
      }

}
```

arduino code:

```
    #include <SPI.h>
#include <MFRC522.h>

#define RST_PIN   26  
#define SS_PIN    5  
#define MISO_PIN  19 
#define MOSI_PIN  23 
#define SCK_PIN   18 


byte incomingByte = Serial.read();

MFRC522 mfrc522(SS_PIN, RST_PIN);

MFRC522::MIFARE_Key key;

void setup() {
    Serial.begin(115200);       // Initialize serial communications with the PC
    pinMode(16,OUTPUT);
    pinMode(21,OUTPUT);
    while (!Serial);        // Do nothing if no serial port is opened (added for Arduinos based on ATMEGA32U4)
    SPI.begin(SCK_PIN, MISO_PIN, MOSI_PIN);
    mfrc522.PCD_Init();     // Init MFRC522
    delay(40);               // Optional delay. Some board do need more time after init to be ready, see Readme
    mfrc522.PCD_DumpVersionToSerial();  // Show details of PCD - MFRC522 Card Reader details

    //dump_byte_array(key.keyByte, MFRC522::MF_KEY_SIZE);
}

void loop() {
    if ( ! mfrc522.PICC_IsNewCardPresent()) {
        return;
    }
    if ( ! mfrc522.PICC_ReadCardSerial()) {
        return;
    }
    if(Serial.available() > 0){
  byte incomingByte = Serial.read();
  
    if (mfrc522.uid.uidByte[0] == incomingByte )/*&&*/ //それぞれ読んだカードの値と比較したい16進数の値を比較
             ) 
    {
        digitalWrite(16,HIGH);
        delay(5000);
        digitalWrite(16,LOW);
        delay(50); 

        
    }
    else{

      digitalWrite(21,HIGH);
      delay(2000);
      digitalWrite(21,LOW);
    }
    }

}
```

as i understand so far, for the arduino i just have to add this to send data from the arduino

```
SerielWrite(a number);
```

what is giving me a headache is how to receive it in java.
i already know that i need rxtx or jseriel libary for my java code.
i also already tryed some examples to recieve a number but it didnt work at all.
does someone maybe has a very easy code to receive a number in java ?

Answer (score 0):

To recieve data in java from the arduino, you need a SerialDataListener to listen for data on the Serial Port. This can be done by creating a class which implements the SerialDataListener interface. This examples just prints to the console whatever data is read from the Serial Port but you can make it do whatever you'd like.

```
import com.fazecast.jSerialComm.*;

public class ComPortListener implements SerialPortDataListener {
    private static String bufferReadToString = ""; // empty, but not null
    private static int cutoffASCII = 10; // ASCII code of the character used for cut-off between received messages

    @Override
    public int getListeningEvents() {
        return SerialPort.LISTENING_EVENT_DATA_AVAILABLE; //returns data on the Serial Port
    }

    @Override
    public void serialEvent(SerialPortEvent event) {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[event.getSerialPort().bytesAvailable()];
        event.getSerialPort().readBytes(buffer, buffer.length);

        String s = new String(buffer);
        bufferReadToString = bufferReadToString.concat(s); //converts the bytes read from the Serial port to a string

        if ((bufferReadToString.indexOf(cutoffASCII) + 1) > 0) {
            System.out.println(bufferReadToString); //prints out the recived data
        }
    }
}
```

To use this, add the following code to your Startup class

```
if (sp.openPort()) {
          System.out.println("Port is open :)");
          ComPortListener listenerObject = new ComPortListener(); //creates new listener object
          serialPort.addDataListener(listenerObject);
        }
```